# Simplify similar loops into one

Tags: ruby, enums

I am writing a braille converter. I have this method to handle the top line of a braille character:

```
def top(input)
  braille = ""
  @output_first = ""
  @top.each do |k, v|
    input.chars.map do |val|
      if k.include?(val)
      braille = val
      braille = braille.gsub(val, v)
      @output_first = @output_first + braille
      end
    end
  end
  @output_first
end
```

I'm repeating the same `each` loop for the middle and bottom lines of a character. The only thing that is different from the method above is that the `@top` is replaced with `@mid` and `@bottom` to correspond to the respective lines.

Trying to figure a way to simplify the `each` loop so I can call it on top, mid and bottom lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the loop in a separate method.

```
def top(input)
  @output_first = handle_line(@top)
end

def handle_line(line)
  result = ''
  line.each do |k, v|
    input.chars.map do |val|
      if k.include?(val)
        braille = val
        braille = braille.gsub(val, v)
        result = result + braille
      end
    end
  end
  result
end
```

You can then call `handle_line` in your `@mid` and `@bottom` processing

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whats in the `@top` var but I believe braille has limited number of characters and therefore I would consider some map structure

```
BRAILLE_MAP = {
  'a' => ['..',' .','. '], # just an example top,mid,bot line for character
  'b' => ['..','..','  '],
  # ... whole map
}

def lines(input)
  top = '' # representation of each line
  mid = ''
  bot = ''
  input.each_char do |c|
    representation = BRAILLE_MAP[c]
    next unless representation # handle invalid char
    top << representation[0] # add representation to each line
    mid << representation[1]
    bot << representation[2]
  end
  [top,mid,bot] # return the lines
end
```

There may be better way to handle those 3 variables, but I cant think of one right now

Comment: that is exactly right. I have a three different hashes for each line of braille. `@top = {"abehkloruvz1258" => "0.",` just one line but I'm sure you get the gist of it.

Comment: in this case the k.include? lookup together with 3 iterations through input text (top,mid,bot) just adds unnecessary work for cpu. I think the map structure mentioned in the answer might be a better solution to your problem unless you are realy short on RAM

Comment: I'm getting `undefined method '[]' for the #<Dictionary:0x007faf8406f9d8>`. I have BRAILLE_MAP defined as dictionary, and in it's own class. I am calling it in `initialize` and setting it as a new instance of that class.

Comment: I've got the map structure working with the code I posted. Working on getting all three to print out at once now, while also simplifying the code. Yours is what I've had in mind.